# Flex project is not executing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 and i've developed one web application in it, now if i try to run the project it is executing in flash player not in browser window, can anybody help how to run this application in web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project go to properties then on the left side select Flex Compiler Settings, on the right side in the bottom select Generate HTML Template.